# Shopify metafield newline_to_br adds line break on anchor tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've added a multi-line metafield to my collections so that I can insert a long description into my template. The code works well, but if there's an anchor tag within the long_description, a line break is added before and after it. Is there a means to stop that from happening?

````
          <div class="content-indent">
            <div class="row tt-layout-promo-box">
              <h3>About Our {{ collection.title }}</h3>
                {{ collection.metafields.my_fields.long_description | newline_to_br }}
            </div>
          </div>{%- endif -%}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let str = document.querySelector('.tt-layout-promo-box h3');
  let stringValue = str.textContent;
  str.innerHTML = parser.parseFromString(stringValue, 'text/html').body.innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: For it to be a good, answer, you should explain it.